# Array loop not working when comparing specific indexes

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compare two arrays together to do some basic math with the same indexes in other arrays.  I am not receiving the correct answer and I think it's because the arrays are not comparing correctly.  Here is my code:

```
    y = 0;
    for (x=0; x<std1.length; x++){
        if (std1[x]==std2[y]){
            sumhrs[x] += hrs[y];
            mult[x] = hrs[y] * ngrd[y];
            hold[x] = hold[x] + mult[x];
            gpa[x] = hold[x] / sumhrs[x];
            y++;
        }
    }
```

The array std1 contains 4 numeric records while the array std2 contains 9 numeric records with multiples (duplicates) of the same records as std1.  The other arrays (hrs, ngrd, etc..) are linked to the same variable [y] because they contain the records in sequence to array std2.

```
    Here is the current output:
    205   Smart   4.0   A
    400   Brent   0.0   NONE
    155   Brown   0.0   NONE
    150   Canon   0.0   NONE
```

This is homework and I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and I cannot.  The end result of this homework is to calculate the GPA from two student files with name and grade information.  I added the files into arrays and then split the arrays into unique arrays with specific format (int, double, string) but kept all duplicates to maintain index accuracy while calculating the GPA.  In other words, array std2[5] and hrs[5] kept the same data that they had when they were one combined array at index [5].

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

***Edit:

I'm going to add my full code and the two files that I'm pulling from here:

```
    File 1tab delimited
    205 Smart
    400 Brent
    155 Brown
    150 Canon
```

```
    File 2tab delimited
    205 1   4.0
    205 3   2.8
    205 4   4.0
    205 3   2.3
    400 3   3.5
    155 2   2.7
    150 3   3.0
    150 3   4.0
    150 3   2.7
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream("c:/users/da/desktop/"
            + "file1.txt");
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
    FileInputStream in2 = new FileInputStream("c:/users/da/desktop/file2.txt");
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

    String[] file1array = new String[4];
    String[] file2array = new String[9];

    for (int j = 0; j < file1array.length; j++){
        file1array[j] = br1.readLine();}
    for (int j = 0; j < file2array.length; j++){
        file2array[j] = br2.readLine();}

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int index = 00;

    int[] std1 = new int [file1array.length];
    String[] name = new String [file1array.length];

    int[] std2 = new int [file2array.length];
    int[] hrs = new int [file2array.length];
    double[] ngrd = new double [file2array.length];
    double[] mult = new double [file2array.length];
    double[] sumhrs = new double [file1array.length];
    double[] hold = new double [file2array.length];

    double[] gpa = new double [file1array.length];
    String[] lgrd = new String [file1array.length];

    String line1 = "";
    String[] data1;
    String line2 = "";
    String[] data2;

    for (x=0; x<file1array.length; x++){
            line1 = file1array[x];
            data1 = line1.split("\t");
            std1[x] = Integer.parseInt(data1[0]);
            name[x] = data1[1];}

    for (x=0; x<file2array.length; x++){
            line2 = file2array[x];
            data2 = line2.split("\t");
            std2[x] = Integer.parseInt(data2[0]);
            hrs[x] = Integer.parseInt(data2[1]);
            ngrd[x] = Double.parseDouble(data2[2]);}

    y = 0;
    for (x=0; x<std1.length; x++){
        if (std1[x]==std2[y]){
            sumhrs[x] += hrs[y];
            mult[x] = hrs[y] * ngrd[y];
            hold[x] = hold[x] + mult[x];
            gpa[x] = hold[x] / sumhrs[x];
            y++;
        }
    }

    for (x=0; x<gpa.length; x++){
        if (gpa[x] <= 4.0){
            lgrd[x] = "A";}
        if (gpa[x] < 3.4){
            lgrd[x] = "B";}
        if (gpa[x] < 3.7){
            lgrd[x] = "C";}
        if (gpa[x] < 2.0){
            lgrd[x] = "D";}
        if (gpa[x] < 1.3){
            lgrd[x] = "F";}
        if (gpa[x] < 0.1){
            lgrd[x] = "NONE";}
    }

    System.out.println ("          STUDENT REPORT");
    System.out.println ("");
    System.out.println ("STUDENT   STUDENT   GPA   GRADE");
    System.out.println (" NUMBER   NAME");
    for (x=0; x<gpa.length; x++)
        System.out.println ("    " + std1[x] + "   " + name[x] + "     " + gpa[x] +
                "   " +lgrd[x]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `y++` should be outside the `if` statement, not inside it.

As it is currently, x gets incremented every time through the for loop, but y only gets incremented if `std1[x] == std2[y]`

Comment: I think you meant to say, "but y only gets incremented ..." Good catch though. +1

Comment: I suppose that I do need the y to increment when true because I need to do the sum of all of the duplicates in the other arrays.  Then when x changes for example from 0 to 1, it will link with y at another point (could be [4]) and it will do the sum of all duplicates from 4 onward until true becomes false.  At least that's the intent and I'm stuck there and I seem to only be showing the first row/index in my output.  The other "students" should be showing their own GPAs instead of 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code you're using for the output so it's easy to see what each column represents?

That aside, I think your problem is that you're not covering all of array `y`. You're looping up to the length of `x`, and if you like you say, y has duplicates, there may be some records you're never accounting for. If you had these arrays:

```
x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
y = 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5
```

Then the values calculated for numbers `4` and `5` would be 0 as the loop would never include them.

You have some code to try and deal with duplicates of y, but it's not going to behave as you're expecting — an inner loop searching `std2` for `std1[x]` will help you on your way.

Comment: Thank you for response, I've added the full code and the example files that I'm using.  I know it's a lot but I'd appreciate any comments that you can give me.  I'll be working on this for the next two to three hours and then I'll have to turn in what I've got.